# Scipy Minimize SLSQP simply returns x0

Tags: python, scipy

I am really new to programming and I am a bit in over my head here with this whole minimize business, so it might just be a simple mistake, but when I try to run my code below, it simply returns the x0 values that I put in to start.

What I'm trying to do:
I have two "functions" that are made up of points, f(x) and h(x). f(X) can be thought of a measured curve, and h(x) is a reference curve. I am trying to use the least squares to find the horizontal shift, x scale, and y scale terms that will best fit the reference curve to the measured results.

I am using the interpolate function to fit a spline to the reference data so the spline can be used to find intermediate values along the curve.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import interpolate


def f(x):
    vals = {1: 0.35, 17: 0.45, 33: 0.67, 49: 0.8, 65: 0.73, 81: 0.65, 97: 0.51, 113: 0.27, 129: 0.01, 145: -0.1,
            161: -0.19, 177: -0.21, 193: -0.2, 209: -0.23, 225: -0.24, 241: -0.25, 257: -0.23, 273: -0.26, 289: -0.28,
            305: -0.22, 321: -0.24, 337: -0.12, 353: 0.14}
    return vals[x]


def h(x):
    vals = {1: -0.2, 17: -0.2, 33: -0.2, 49: -0.2, 65: -0.2, 81: -0.2, 97: -0.2, 113: -0.2, 129: -0.1, 145: 0.1,
            161: 0.32, 177: 0.4, 193: 0.7, 209: 0.81, 225: 0.7, 241: 0.6, 257: 0.5, 273: 0.3, 289: 0, 305: -0.1,
            321: -0.2, 337: -0.2, 353: -0.2}
    return vals[x]


x1 = []
y1 = []

for i in range(1, 365, 16):
    x1.append(i)
    y1.append(h(i))

tck = interpolate.splrep(x1, y1)

fun = lambda x: ((1 / 22.8125 * numpy.sum(
    (f(i) - (x[0] * interpolate.splev((x[1] * (i + x[2]) + 0.5), tck)) - 0.5) ** 2 for i in range(1, 365, 16))) ** (
                     1 / 2))

bnds = ((0.3, 1.5), (0.3, 1.5), (0, 150))

res = optimize.minimize(fun, (1, 1, 0), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)

print res.x
```

Again, when I run this I simply get [1.0, 1.0, 0.0] for res.x. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1 / 2` in Python2 without `from __future__ import division` is equal to `0`, and this seems to be what's causing your problem. After replacement with `0.5` or `1./2`, I get

```
[  3.00000000e-01   1.14967789e+00   7.48854782e-04]
```

for `res.x`.